# как работает инклюд в nodejs

Tags: node.js

как на nodejs реализовать include как например в php? чтоб в один файл js подключался другой файл js

Comment: Это ведь в любом примере на node.js есть

Comment: что есть???? как добавлять один написанный .js  в другой как на php функция include ????? нету такого

Comment: не так прочитали вопрос и начинаете комментировать, есть, нету, в любом учебнике....

Comment: Если ожидаете получить поведение точно такое же как в php, так как он включает include скрипт в контекст скрипта в котором делается include, и все переменные глобальные в файле который include'ли становятся доступны в вызывающем скрипте, то нет, такое в node не работает. УЧИТЕ ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЮ, это вы не почитали документацию и начинаете уже вопросы задавать

Comment: так я и спросил, может есть мысли как реализовать

Comment: может кто-то реализовывал подобное

Comment: Нет, неявного объединения контекстов там не сделать к счастью.. Только явные импорты

Comment: В голову приходит только если чтение файла целиком и `eval`.

Comment: eval... кстати да, как вариант...

Answer (score 2):

require()

```js
var fs = require("fs");
```

Comment: чтобы воспользоваться функциями, переменными и т.д нужно их експортировать (это основы node.js)

Comment: почитайте внимательней мой вопрос

Comment: я не имел ввиду импорт модулей

Answer (score 0):

Для включения скриптов друг в друга используется

```
const sum = require('./sum');
```

А внутри sum.js вот такой экспорт

```
module.exports = (a, b) => a + b
```

Вот документация по модулям https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html